# gradle fail to sync due to dependencies fail

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

when starting android studio everything is loading as expected except from the gradle.
it's give me two errors:

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.mini_window_style.ext:junit:1.1.1
Failed to resolve: androidx.mini_window_style.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0
```

the app is loading when i hit run but i can't see my xml files

those are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.mini_window_style.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.mini_window_style.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these dependencies:

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.mini_window_style.ext:junit:1.1.1'

androidTestImplementation
'androidx.mini_window_style.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'